# Exception is always NULL

Tags: android, exception

Why will the Android "Catch" handler not initialize an Exception object?

When an error occurs and my code is trying to initialize an Exception object it is *always* NULL.

The above doesn't make sense to me, because the exception should always initialize the Exception object - *period*. It should never be null if an error occurs.

I am fairly new to the Eclipse Android IDE/SDK, and I am sure I don't have everything set up 100%. However, this type of functionality would seem to me that it should work all the time, not after being set up.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your code? What evidence have you used to arrive at the conclusion that the exception is null? How did you observe this evidence?

Comment: Hi, I have the below handler setup:  catch(Exception ex)
        {
         System.out.println("ERROR:\n\n" + ex.toString());
        }                                                              When I run debug, the exception is always NULL....regardless of what the error is. It never initializes

Comment: You have a break point within the catch block, and ex is null?  I find that hard to believe... If ex was null, your print statement would throw a null pointer exception, is that what happens?

Comment: Yes, a NULL pointer exception is thrown. The main invoked method is a HTTP call. I originally was getting a HOSTNOTFOUND exception because my LAN connection was not working. However, when I started Eclipse today, the exception is not being thrown any longer. The Exception object is just not initializing.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Good Lord!!....does nobody have any idea why this error is occurring? Has nobody ever experience this issue besides me?

Comment: I'm having the same stupid error right now. How come something can throw null? This is definitely a Dalvik error.

Comment: I still see this happening once in awhile. Is rather unhelpful!

Answer (score 6):

One possible cause is that you are trying to make a network connection on your main thread, which works fine pre-2.3.3/Honeycomb (SDK level < 10 for example) but will be thrown as an

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

since SDK level 10.

Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

The problem is that Eclipse doesn't really know about this exception (since it is conditionally thrown based on different SDK level so Eclipse probably can't get a correct instance of this exception, that explains why your exception object is always NULL)

Solution: create a separate thread or use AsyncTask to perform your network connection request.

Comment: How is it possible to invoke the exception handler without an instance of the exception?  The exception handler code must effectively test `thrownException instanceof CatchException`, and without an instance of the exception that's gonna fail.