# IOException e is null

Tags: java, android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception is NULL always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949609/exception-is-null-always)

I've got a strange problem with an IOException object and couldn't find an answer for this.

Code looks like this:

```
try { // This isn't very important part, but maybe it has something to do with a problem
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
  StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
  int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
  if (statusCode == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      builder.append(line);
    }
  } else {
    Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I'm here in the IOException catch clause");
        e.printStackTrace(); // e is null (line 126)
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Program catches `IOException`, but its object (e) is `null`. How is this possible?

Edit: Stack Trace:

```
09-25 19:35:59.438: I/System.out(31732): I'm here in the IOException catch clause
09-25 19:36:04.377: W/dalvikvm(31732): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uniwersytet.ekiosk/uniwersytet.ekiosk.EkioskActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at uniwersytet.ekiosk.EkioskActivity.onCreate(EkioskActivity.java:126)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-25 19:36:04.447: E/AndroidRuntime(31732):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Just a tip. If you catch `Exception e`, you don't need to catch any other `Exception` class because those are children of `Exception` class.

Comment: Do you get a Exception because of a Exception? "y0 dawg, I hear you like Exception inside Exception" - Xzibit

Comment: How do you know that `e` is null?

Comment: can you include the stack trace?

Comment: It seems that lots of "impossible" things are possible with android. It is at least the second time I encounter the error that can not happen or does not make any sense.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace, I highly doubt that is what is actually occurring -- in Java `throw null` actually throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @tolgap and Mosquito: Don't catch Exception in general with `Exception e`. See here: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I got a NullPointerException after trying to call printStackTrace() for e.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400711/java-exception-itself-is-null and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949609/exception-is-null-always

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at uniwersytet.ekiosk.EkioskActivity.onCreate(EkioskActivity.java:125)` What is line 125 in EkioskActivity?

Comment: what's about (EkioskActivity.java:125)

Comment: @Sam line 125 is e.printStackTrace() for IOException

Comment: Interesting, is there more to the LogCat?

Comment: are you executing an http request on the Main Thread?

Comment: I suspect that you simply have a line numbering problem.

Comment: (Hint: Before doing the printStackTrace do a `System.out.println("I'm here in the IOException catch clause");`.)

Comment: @HotLicks Added System.out.println() and posted new stack trace

Comment: @blackbelt Yes, it's in the Main Thread

Comment: Well, it looks like Dalvik is screwing up -- branching to the wrong resume point after catching the exception.  How big is the procedure, and how many other catch clauses are there in it?

Comment: (Or actually, it may be "falling through" from the `try` range.  Try putting a println statement in the last line of the `try` range.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Please check the `response` you are getting from the Server.

**-** Please also take note of it... that `UI work should be on UI thread and Non-UI work on the Non-UI thread`, from HoneyComb Version of Android it became a rule.

**-** Please use a `thread with handler`, or `AsyncTask` for this kind of long time taking tasks.